# Redirect output from multiple child processes in bash script

Tags: macos, bash, stdout, child-process

I'm developing this script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# If no command line arguments, display a tiny usage message.
if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]; then
  echo "Usage: $0 files..." >&2
  exit 1
fi

# Destroy child processes, when exiting.
cleanup() {
  kill `jobs -p` 2>/dev/null
}

# Call cleanup function on SIGINT, ie. Ctrl-C.
trap "cleanup; exit 0" INT TERM EXIT

# Start child processes continously outputting from the files given as command
# line arguments. The filename is prepended on the line.
for f in $*; do
  tail -f "$f" | awk '{ print "'"$f"':"$0 }' &
done

# Wait for child processes to exit. Just to be sure, kill them all afterwards.
wait
cleanup
```

I use it like this:

```bash
tailfiles *.log
```

What it does is interleaving the tail output from all the files, prepended with the filename (a bit like `grep -H` does). However, I can not pipe the output of the script. It simple gives me nothing:

```bash
tailfiles *.log | grep error
```

Is it possible in bash to collect streams from multiple child processes into one output?

Comment: This script should work. What kind of errors are you trying to collect? Are you sure that they're coming from ``stdout`` and not ``stderr`` ?

Comment: You have `&` and your `tail`s are run in the background. Try something like `tail $list_of_all_files` or redirect the `tail`s to some output (like file or pipe)

Comment: @Aleks-DanielJakimenko, I'm developing this script for some repetitive tasks I'm doing, going through some big log files for specific information. The actual process is a bit more involved, so the above is just an example. What I want is a `tail` command that prepends the filename on each line, so I'm able to track the information.

Comment: @JakubM., thanks for your suggestion. I know `tail` can output multiple files, but unfortunately it does not prepend the filename on each line and I haven't been able to find any tool that does. This means I lose the filename information in the stream, and I need to track that further down the line.

Comment: Can it be related to the way bash works on Mac OS X? I haven't had the possibility to try running the script on a Linux box yet.

Comment: Btw, shouldn't you escape the single quotes near `$f` in `awk`?

Answer (score 1):

try the following:

```
# ...
rm -f fifo
mkfifo fifo
for f in $*; do
  tail -f "$f" | awk '{ print "'"$f"':"$0 }'  > fifo  &
done

tail -f fifo
# ...
```

Comment: I tried this, but it gives me no output at all (on both stdout and stderr).

Answer (score 1):

You probably just have to change the loop to this:

```
for f; do
  tail -f "$f" | awk -v f="$f" '{ printf "%s : %s\n", f, $0 }' &
done
```

Using $* would make it subject to word splitting.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about $*, I removed that. Although using your `awk` command does not solve my issue. The script still functions when run alone, but when I pipe the output from my script into another process (like `grep` or `cat`) it simply gives no output (on both stdout and stderr).

Comment: What I meant to say is, that your code is definitely more readable than mine (I'll use it). However, my script behaves the same way.

Comment: @BjarkeWalling I could run multiple background `tail -f` functions on my Linux box and all processes send lines to a pipe or a file. Perhaps it's OSX related? Or maybe it depends on `tail`.

Comment: I ran this command and it works: `( tail -f a & tail -f b & ) > out` and also `( tail -f a & tail -f b & ) | cat > out`. Which I think is also the same as `bash script.sh | cat > out`.